# Banner Saga - Only 2 armor damage?

Tags: the-banner-saga

[image]

So I'm gonna do 4 health damage because 12 minus 8 equals 4. How is the armor damage calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The armor damage doesn't get calucalated at all. Armor Damage is its own character stat called "Break".